# how to make the fraction appear in the middle of the big bracket?

Tags: fractions

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{9}}
\makeatother
\citestyle{apa}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{\textbf{General Review}}\label{cp1}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{align}
+\delta_{I_i}\vast\[\frac{
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\bigg(-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma^2}(1-e^{\gamma t_{L_i}})-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(t_{L_i}e^{\gamma t_{L_i}})\bigg)e^{\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_{L_i}})}-$\\
$\bigg(-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma^2}(1-e^{\gamma t_{U_i}})-\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(t_{U_i}e^{\gamma t_{U_i}})\bigg)e^{\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_{U_i}})}$
\end{tabular}}
{e^{\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_{L_i}})}-e^{\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i}}}{\gamma}(1-e^{\gamma t_{U_i}})}}\vast\]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0FeJ.png]

is there any way to make the fraction appear in the middle of the big bracket?

Comment: Note the fraction bar is aligned with the + on the outside, and large brackets are vertically centred, which is why the result is as it is. You should probably clarify whether you want to move down (vertically centre) the fraction or move up the brackets, either of which would result in smaller brackets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue of providing large outer brackets becomes irrelevant if you decide to simplify the equation by using a one-letter variable, say `Q`, to denote the term `\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i})/\gamma`, which occurs no fewer than 8 [!] times in the equation; see the first equation below for the result of this substitution. (You're obviously free to choose a different variable name.)

If you believe that it's necessary to place curly braces around the split numerator, go ahead and do so; see the second equation below for the resulting look.

Observe that I've used the `\splitdfrac` macro (provided by the `mathtools` package) to typeset the two-line numerator term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\splitdfrac' macro
\newcommand\Q{\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_{1i})/\gamma}
\begin{document}
Put $Q=\Q$. Then
\begin{equation}
\dots+\delta_{I_i} \frac{%
\splitdfrac{
[-(Q/\gamma)(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})-
   Q(t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]
\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]}{
-[-(Q/\gamma)(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}}) 
  -Q(t_{\mkern-1muU_i}e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]
\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]
}}{\displaystyle
 \exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]
-\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} % same equation, but curly braces around numerator
\dots+\delta_{I_i} \frac{\biggl\{
\splitdfrac{
[-(Q/\gamma)(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})-
   Q(t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]
\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]}{
-[-(Q/\gamma)(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}}) 
  -Q(t_{\mkern-1muU_i}e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]
\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]
}\biggr\} }{\displaystyle
 \exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1.5muL_i}})]
-\exp[Q(1-e^{\gamma t_{\mkern-1muU_i}})]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I have not undestood :-) the question. My English is very bad.

Comment: @Sebastiano  - Thanks! As you noticed, I chose to answer the OP's question rather differently than what he/she had in mind. :-)

Comment: Is there yet the fog in your mind? ahahahhah :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - Nah, the ol' crystal bowl appears to be working alright today (judging by the fact that the OP chose to "accept" my answer...) Dense fog to return soon, though, I'm quite sure!

Answer (score 4):

In any case, the main fraction line should be kept on the math axis. Otherwise, it can change the math meaning, see double fractions.

The following example first moves the inner formula to center it in the box around the math axis. The fences are added that are now close without excess of white space above or below. Finally, the formula with fences is moved in the opposite direction to keep the math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\shortenfences}[3]{%
  % #1: left fence without \left
  % #2: formula inside the fences
  % #3: right fence without \right
  \mathpalette{\@shortenfences{#1}{#3}}{#2}%
}
\newdimen\sf@dimen
\newcommand*{\@shortenfences}[4]{%
  % #1: left fence
  % #2: right fence
  % #3: math style
  % #4: formula
  \sbox0{$#3#4\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#3\vcenter{}$}%
  % \dimen0: height above math axis
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0 - \ht2\relax
  \ifdim\dimen0<\z@
    \dimen0=\z@
  \fi
  % \dimen2: depth below math axis
  \dimen2=\dimexpr\ht2 + \dp0\relax
  \ifdim\dimen2<\z@
    \dimen2=\z@
  \fi
  % \sf@dimen: amount for lowering the inner formula
  % to center the inner formula.
  \sf@dimen=\dimexpr(\dimen0 - \dimen2)/2\relax
  % lower the inner formula and raise the outer formula with
  % the fences to keep the math axis.
  \raisebox{\sf@dimen}{%
    $#3\left#1\raisebox{-\sf@dimen}{\box0}\right#2\m@th$%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \alpha =
  \left[
    \dfrac{
      \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^n f(i)}{a + b}
    }{c - d}
  \right]^\gamma
  =
  \shortenfences{[}{
    \dfrac{
      \dfrac{\sum\limits_i^n f(i)}{a + b}
    }{c - d}
  }{]^\gamma}
  = 0
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]