# LaTeX: how to get correct size/position of (nested) brackets around fractions

Tags: size, brackets

In the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\x}%
           {a = \left[%
                  \frac{b}%
                       {c + \left[ \frac de%
                            \right]%
                       }%
                \right]%
           }

\begin{document}

1.A
$\x$
1.B

2.A
\[ \x \]
2.B

3.A \footnote{3.C
$\x$ 3.D}
3.B

4.A \footnote{4.C
\[ \x \] 4.D}
4.B

\end{document}
```

the outer brackts are too big in "part" 1, 3 and 4.
They are much higher than the whole fraction, because obviously they are drawn symmetrically to the main fraction bar. But as the denominator is bigger than the numerator the result is not satisfying.

In "part" 2 they have the correct size, just enclosing the whole fraction but not more. So the different sizes of numerator and denominator are taken into account.

How can I get the correct size also in 1, 3 and 4?

Part 2:

[image: formula 2]

Part 4:

[image: formula 4]

Part 1:

[image: formula 1]

Part 3:

[image: formula 3]

Comment: It seems that you have a naked `\frac`. Doesn't it cause problems?

Comment: @TomSolid It's not naked because \frac de = \frac{d}{e}

Comment: Just for the record: I did vote to migrate this Q. Unfortunately a mod closed it as "needs details or clarity" instead, which it again total nonsense. The question has all the necessary information and clearly phrased

Comment: @SamuelLiew Can you please stop mass-closing clear and well posted questions as "needs details or clarity" That must be terrible confusing for the OPs

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I voted to migrate - that is very different than "unclear".

Comment: yeah, sorry, just saw the history!

Comment: @SandwichX: Actually they are the correct sizes, since the braces are vertically centered around the math axis. Therefore, they stretch just as far upward as downward, regardless of the math style. Perhaps you can provide a visual of what you expect the brackets should look like... even if using some graphical editor to change the sizes to suit your needs. Can you do that?

Comment: @all: Thanks for all your comments and help!

Comment: @Werner: Yes, you are right; now I see that also in part 2 the braces are vertically centered. But formula 2 looks much better as there is not so much empty space above the "b" as it is in the other three formulas. I guess it is something about the fontsizes of the letters and the distances to the fraction bar. I have extracted and magnified the four formulas from the output and put it into my question.

Comment: So the real question now is: How can I make the formula look as "nice" (meaning: not so much empty space in the upper part)  as it is in \[ \]-mode when being in $ $-mode or footnote-mode?

Answer (score 2):

I can assure you that placing content in a non-centered way around the horizontal math axis doesn't provide something that is nicer. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418205/5764), for example, where it lists as an option an updated fencing mechanism:

[image]

Instead, if your visual concerns stem from something within a footnote, I'd suggest rewriting the expression in a linear way:

```
\footnote{... $a = b / [ c + ( d / e ) ]$ ...}
```

and/or add the appropriate brackets/fences if you're concerned about misinterpretation. The benefit from using this approach is that it won't affect the line spacing which is common when using large (vertical) expressions in inline math mode.